Center number over word
I'm making a markscheme for a translation. Ideally I'd like the mark per word to be centered over the relevant word.
(Also, if any of this could be done a better way please do say).
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{sentence}
\newcounter{total}

\setcounter{sentence}{0}
\setcounter{total}{0}



\newcommand{\word}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}\addtocounter{sentence}{#1}\addtocounter{total}{#1}}

\newcommand{\sentencetotal}{\textbf{\arabic{sentence}} \setcounter{sentence}{0}}

This\word{1} is\word{1} a sentence\word{2}.\sentencetotal 

It\word{1} has\word{1} marks\word{2} for\word{1} words\word{1}.\sentencetotal 

Total: \arabic{total}

\end{document}



\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}1\\word\end{tabular}

You can do it with tabular, with some trick.
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{sentences}{}
  {\par\addvspace{\topsep}\linespread{1.6}\selectfont}
  {\par\addvspace{\topsep}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\sentence}{m}{%
  \setcounter{partialsum}{0}%
  #1~\textbf{\arabic{partialsum}}\addtocounter{totalsum}{\value{partialsum}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\w}{mm}{%
  \addtocounter{partialsum}{#2}%
  \begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \scriptsize#2\\
    \noalign{\vskip2pt}
    \vphantom{A}#1
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcounter{partialsum}
\newcounter{totalsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{sentences}
\sentence{\w{This}{1} \w{is}{1} a \w{sentence}{2}.}

\sentence{\w{It}{1} \w{has}{1} \w{marks}{2} \w{for}{1} \w{words}{1}.}
\end{sentences}

Total: \thetotalsum

\end{document}



Really clever thanks and works with line numbers, which I forgot to mention as a thing. Thanks
